# FuncAnimation doesn't display animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-animation, matplotlib-widget

I have code that is running on a different machine.

```
%matplotlib widget

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

n = 100
x = np.random.randn(n)

def update(curr):
    if curr == n:
        a.event_source.stop()
    plt.cla()
    bins = np.arange(-4, 4, 0.5)
    plt.hist(x[:curr], bins=bins)
    plt.axis([-4,4,0,30])
    plt.gca().set_title('Sampling the Normal Distribution')
    plt.gca().set_ylabel('Frequency')
    plt.gca().set_xlabel('Value')
    plt.annotate('n = {}'.format(curr), [3,27])
a = animation.FuncAnimation(plt.figure(), update, interval=100)

plt.show()
```

[However, it gives me this every time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81M5n.png)

And some times: "UserWarning: Animation was deleted without rendering anything. This is most likely not intended. To prevent deletion, assign the Animation to a variable, e.g. `anim`, that exists until you output the Animation using `plt.show()` or `anim.save()`."

I installed ipympl, restarted kernel, IDE, computer, removed "%matplotlib widget", but all this didn't help.
I hope you'll give me a hand

UPDATE:
I checked several examples of working code and found out 2 things:

1. All code including this one generates the correct animation, if you save it in any format (mp4, html), you can see it
2. If the animation is saved, then plt.show() will show the last frame, if not, then as in the picture above

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please share information about your matplotlib and Python version and the IDE you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, and the only workaround I've found is to save the animation and then read it back from the file:

```
from IPython.display import Image
f = r'test_animation.gif'
writergif = animation.PillowWriter(fps=10)
a.save(f,writer=writergif)
plt.close()
Image(open('test_animation.gif','rb').read())
```